# Which layout for this gui?

Tags: pyqt6

I would like to create a GUI as follows:

[image: img]

So far, I could manage something with a Dialog layout but there I have e.g. only a label left and a qlineedit next to it. But I need several input fields, that's why I aiming at gridlayout but I can't manage to get a simple example working. Lots of code snippets I find do not work or need adjustments I'm not aware of as a rookie.

Could someone show me some code to make the displayed example working?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Why don't you start by doing some tests with [Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/designer-layouts.html)?

Comment: Thanks for the input! This is Qt, right? I'm using pyqt. Tbh, I'm not sure what's the difference. It looks like Qt is a standalone software while i can use pyqt right away in the python code?

Comment: PyQt (as PySide) is just a python binding around the C++ based Qt library. So, fundamentally, there's no difference: you *are* using Qt, just through another programming language.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. My python code exists already, would you suggest to use Qt as standalone though or to stay with pyqt? Qt looks interesting but the GUI I need is rather basic.

Comment: No, you haven't understood: you are **already** using Qt. And you don't use "Qt as standalone", because Qt is a *toolkit* (a "library"), it doesn't do anything on its own. Designer is a *tool* that can help you to create the UI, which you can then integrate with the logic of your program. Please do more research and reading on these subjects, as they are fundamental aspects you cannot ignore nor get confused about.

Comment: https://www.qt.io/contact-us/request-a-free-trial?utm_term=qt&utm_campaign=Buy+Qt&utm_source=adwords&utm_medium=ppc&hsa_acc=7519109677&hsa_net=adwords&hsa_cam=1485529402&hsa_ad=486256676787&hsa_kw=qt&hsa_grp=114656221389&hsa_mt=e&hsa_ver=3&hsa_src=g&hsa_tgt=kwd-49508282&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI5cnJhZHJ-gIVlZ93Ch1FwQiPEAAYASAAEgLLQPD_BwE isn't a software I can download and open as an individual instance?

Comment: Do know the difference between a development tool and a library/framework/toolkit? Do you understand what is Qt and how its python bindings work?

Comment: I would have said yes but I believe it turns out I don't :) I would say a framework/toolkit is something like a library I would load in my code/IDE whereas a development tool is (something like) an IDE?

Comment: Yes. Qt is the whole toolkit, which includes various modules that can be loaded in the code (what allows your code to show widgets, make the user interact with it, etc). A complex toolkit as Qt is, normally provides a set of programs (tools) that help developers to code or create certain aspects of their applications: Designer is part of the *toolkit*, since it's a *tool* that helps you *develop* your program; specifically, it allows to create the *graphical interface*, but not code the "logic". If you don't have designer, install `pyqt6-tools` with pip.